# Relay Modern fragment error (expect object to contain data....)

Tags: reactjs, graphql, relay, django-filter, graphene-python

I am using Relay and django-graphene version 2. Country.js is rendering av list of countries.

Using fragments I get this error:
Warning: RelayModernSelector: Expected object to contain data for fragment `Country_country`, got `{"node":{"__fragments":{"Country_country":{}},"__id":"Q291bnRyeVR5cGU6MQ=="}}`. Make sure that the parent operation/fragment included fragment `...Country_country` without `@relay(mask: false)`.

The QueryRenderer returns the correct list of countries without Country_country, just putting in the variable name.

```
<QueryRenderer
      environment={environment}
      query={graphql`query CartContainerQuery {
        viewer {
          id
          countries(first: 3) {
            edges {
              node {
                ...Country_country
              }
            }
            pageInfo {
              startCursor
              endCursor
            }
          }

      }
      }`}
      variables={{}}
      render={({error, props}) => {
        if (error) {
          console.log(error)
          return <div>Error!</div>;
        }
        if (!props) {
          return <div>Loading...</div>;
        }
        return (
          <div>
          {console.log(props)}
          <Country country={props.viewer.countries.edges} />
          </div>
        );
      }}
    />
```

My fragment on Contry Container:

```
export default createFragmentContainer(
   Country,
   graphql`
   fragment Country_country on CountryType @relay(plural: true) {
       id
       name
     }
   `
 )
```

Graphene Schema:

```
class CountryType(DjangoObjectType, model=Country):
  class Meta:
    interfaces= (relay.Node,)
    filter_fields = ['name', 'id']

class Viewer(graphene.ObjectType):
  class Meta:
    interfaces = [relay.Node, ]

  countries = DjangoFilterConnectionField(CountryType)
  country = graphene.List(CountryType)

  def resolve_country(self, info, **kwargs):
    return Country.objects.all()

  def resolve_countries(self, info, **kwargs):
    return Country.objects.all()

class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
  viewer = graphene.Field(Viewer)
  node = relay.Node.Field()

  def resolve_viewer(self, info):
    return Viewer()
```

If I try this query in QueryRenderer it also works fine:

```
query={graphql`query CartContainerQuery {
            viewer {
              id
              country {
                  ...Country_country
                }
            }
          }`}
```

Am I using DjangoFilterConnectionField falsely?

Answer (score 0):

As I know and test right now, your graphene side is ok and the bug is from the ReactJS side, that's mean you are using DjangoFilterConnectionField truly.

I have a lot of research about this but as I didn't see your React code completely, I have a little doubtful. anyway as I saw in this sample([Query](https://github.com/apollographql/relay-modern-hello-world/blob/master/src/App.js#L32), [Fragment](https://github.com/apollographql/relay-modern-hello-world/blob/master/src/Feed.js#L21)) you are using this wrong:

```
<Country country={props.viewer.countries.edges} />
```

You should use it like this:

```
<Country country={props.viewer.countries} />
```

as far as I understand you are required to pass the queried object to the child